# How come I cannot create a new nib file in XCode?

Tags: xcode, ios

I am trying to create a new nib file in my empty iPhone application project in XCode.

I go to File -> New, after which XCode presents me with these options.

[image]

I tried selecting "Objective-C category" and then selecting "UINib."

[image]

However, doing so just created a .h and .m file instead of a .xib file. How do I create new nib (.xib) file in XCode 4.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under iOS (in your first screenshot) select `User Interface`, from there you can select `Empty` to add a blank nib.  There are also options there to create initial nibs for a View, Window, or Application.